# Create Commenting system backend server with JAVA Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, comments

I would like to implement a commenting system with JAVA Backend API server which should have the following features.

1. User can post any message or image
2. Any users can put their comments on their own post or other users post
3. Any users can like/unlike other users post/comments

So, basically I want to store user, posts, comments, like/dislike counts. What relational database or storage system (like redis) do I need to use here?

I already tried redis for storing like/dislike count, comment for a post. But I unable to store user, post details effectively as like structured database. But redis does the job fine for increment/decrement like/dislike count

My data structure looks like below

```
**Users:**

id
first_tname
last_name
email
created_at
updated_at

**Posts:**

id
post_message
created_at
updated_at

**Likes:**

id
type -> post (1)/comment(2)
activity_id

**Comments:**

id
message
activity_id
created_at
updated_at 

**Activities:**

id
user_id
like_id
comment_id
```

Comment: *Please suggest.* Stackoverflow is a Q&A (Question and Answer) where the question must be as specific as possible. Like *I use X and encounter Y, my setup is Z*. Your question though is: *I want to achieve A*. No problem statement, no errors, no specific setup. Which makes *answering* your "question" **very** hard

Comment: @LinosaysReinstateMonica Thanks for your input. I edited my question with the approach I have tried. I really need help on better architectural design (data store). I mean which database or datastore does job fine for my requirement in terms of query performance on load and should work fine if multiple users upload their comments at a time on same post. Any guide or help document would be helpful here